# Powershell array values on separate lines

Tags: powershell

So I have written this simple script to show me all users who have mailbox automapped to their account.  Basically there is an AD attribute msExchDelegateListBL that contains the names of those mailboxes.  With my very limited PS knowledge pulling these values out of an array was a little challenging.  This is what I ended up with (I'm sure there is a MUCH better way to do this):

```
Get-content C:\users.txt | Get-ADUser -Properties msExchDelegateListBL,targetaddress,mail | 
select name, 
@{L='Mailbox1';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[0]}},
@{L='Mailbox2';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[1]}},
@{L='Mailbox3';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[2]}},
@{L='Mailbox4';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[3]}},
@{L='Mailbox5';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[4]}},
@{L='Mailbox6';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[5]}},
@{L='Mailbox7';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[6]}},
@{L='Mailbox8';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[7]}},
@{L='Mailbox9';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[8]}},
@{L='Mailbox10';E={$_.msExchDelegateListBL[9]}}
|sort -Property name | Export-Csv C:\list.csv
```

This script shows the name of the user then lists each mailbox (up to 10) and appends it to a csv file so if the user has multiple values in that attribute, it lists them in a new column.  So it looks like this:

```
name        Mailbox1                     Mailbox2
User1,Test  CN=MailboxName,OU=Exchange  CN=MailboxName,OU=Exchange
User2,Test  CN=MailboxName,OU=Exchange  CN=MailboxName,OU=Exchange
```

What I really need is a way to just list out the mailboxes, each on a separate line, not a seperate column. I can do without the name but really need all the values in that AD atttribute (msExchDelegateListBL) put on individual lines not columns.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that since you already have an array (`msExchDelegateListBL`) you don't need to split a value first as described in the answer to the other question.

Comment: wow this is much simpler than I thought it would be...  Import-Csv C:\users.csv | ForEach-Object{$_| Select-Object}  -  this gets me what I need but is there a way to filter out the rows that have no data in them?  BTW - TY

Comment: so when I run that command, the output looks correct on screen but when I export to csv it goes back to putting the data into additional colums like it did before instead of rows, arghhhh

Comment: Please post a new question with the code you currently have as well as a sample of desired and actual output.